# Point dynamic keys to one object

Tags: javascript

How to point dynamic keys to one object, example:

```
[id, name] : {age: 40, weight: 70, height: 170}
```

I know that JS doesn't has multimap, but what is best way to implement such case?

Comment: That is a part of a JS expression, but invalid on its own. Can you complete the code so that it is syntactically correct?

Answer (score 4):

Just assign it separately:

```
let obj = { age: 40, weight: 70, height: 170};
let multiref = {
    id: obj,
    name: obj
};
```

As proof, you could mutate `obj` and see that this change is visible in both these properties:

```js
let obj = { age: 40, weight: 70, height: 170};
let multiref = {
    id: obj,
    name: obj
};
obj.age++; // My birthday today!
obj.weight += 3; // Christmas turkey!
console.log(multiref.id.age, multiref.name.age); // 41, 41
console.log(multiref.id === multiref.name); // true
```

If the names of the keys are dynamic, you can of course still use computed property names:

```js
let obj = { age: 40, weight: 70, height: 170};
let id = "a";
let name = "b";
let multiref = {
    [id]: obj,
    [name]: obj
};
console.log(multiref); // Stack Snippet will detect multi reference
```

And if the *number* of such keys is dynamic too, you can make a loop, for instance with `Object.fromEntries` -- but there are many other ways to do it:

```js
let obj = { age: 40, weight: 70, height: 170};
let keys = ["a", "b"];
let multiref = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, obj]));
console.log(multiref); // Stack Snippet will detect multi reference
```

NB: The virtual console that [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) provides, has same-reference detection, which is why you see these `/**ref:2**/` appearing. This is actually useful for this question, as it proves that there is only one object assigned to multiple properties.

Comment: You can log `JSON.stringify(multiref, null, 2)` to avoid the ref thingy in snippet console

Comment: Yes, but I actually liked it, so I left it like that. It proves that they are the same reference.